# set dropdown selected text from comma seperated values

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am tring to set selected values in a dropdown from a comma seperated string,here i want to set text1,text2,text3,text4 as selected in the dropdown.

Thanks..

```
var string='text1,text2,text3,text4';

<select id="dropdown">
    <option value="0">text1</option>
    <option value="1">text2</option>
    <option value="2">text3</option>
    <option value="3">text4</option>
    <option value="4">text5</option>
    <option value="5">text6</option>
    <option value="6">text7</option>
</select>
```

Comment: `for(var i=0;i<string.split(",").length -1;i++){ ... Add options here }`

Comment: inside he for loop how can i set the dropdown selected based on the splitted string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here we go, you can make selected values like following:

```
var string='text1,text2,text3,text4';
var opts = string.split(",");
function selectOptions() {
    var obj = $('#dropdown');
    for (var i in opts) {
        obj.find('option[value=' + i + ']').prop('selected', true);
    }
}
selectOptions();
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/xEwyd/4/)

Hope this will work!

Comment: you know that in your fiddle, the select is actually created by the html part, your js code has nothing to do with it... did I misunderstand the OP that they actually wanted to populate the data into the select using jquery...?

Comment: @webeno Sorry! just re-checking it!

Comment: i dont want to append i just want to to make the dropdown selected

Comment: Ohh God.. You should have mentioned it like multiple dropdown ;-) if it isn't multiple select then you can't do this!

Comment: @user1851420 See My updated answer hope you wanted like that!

Comment: there is an issue if i change the order its not working for example var string='text1,text3,text4';

Comment: if i use this var string='text2'; then it's selecting the first one text1

Comment: @user1851420 Create another thread/question reproducing the issue!

Comment: created another question

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `string.split(',')`